beginner: "half background" and positioning
Im doing my very first steps in tikz, so even the small thing I show now took some hours to find out :)
I try to copy a diagram, already existing. It's showing a process.
First question: box 10 should be a little higher, to be exact: between 7 and 8 to the right-hand side. It's a result of box 7 and 8, so 2 arrows should come from these two boxes, merge together, and point at box 10 in one single arrow... i don't know how to set the correct position for box 10, nor do I know how to draw that specific arrow.
Second question: This whole process got two headlines, written next to each other, above the picture shown here. The significant point in this process is on half of box 5. So in the original picture, these two headlines meet/split there.
First headline is starting above box 1, reaching half of box 5. Second headline starting at the other half of box 5 till the end on the right (box 10) plus it got a gray background allover the entire diagram. It's hard to describe, but I hope it's understandable. The background color of the right side of the entire picture is slightly gray. Other side white. Two normal headlines above the picture you can see here.
I'm very thankful for help.

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [every text node part/.style={align=center}]


\tikzstyle{box1} = [rectangle, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{pfeil1} = [draw=black, -stealth]

%boxes:
\node[box1] (v1) at (0,0) {box 1 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v2) [below=of v1] {box 2 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v3) [below=of v2] {box 3 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v4) [right=of v2] {box 4 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v5) [right=of v4] {box 5 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v6) [right=of v5] {box 6 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v7) [below=of v6] {box 7 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v8) [below=of v7] {box 8 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v9) [below=of v8] {box 9 \\ dd \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v10) [right=of v8] {\textit{box 10}};


%signs
\draw [draw=white] (v1) -- node {+} (v2);
\draw [draw=white] (v2) -- node {+} (v3);
\draw [draw=white] (v2) -- node {=} (v4);

%arrows
\draw [pfeil1] (v4) -- (v5);
\draw [pfeil1] (v5) -- (v6);
\draw [pfeil1] (v6) -- (v7);
\draw [pfeil1] (v7) -- (v8);
\draw [pfeil1] (v8) -- (v9);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

EDIT: So this is looking really ugly now, because for whatever reason the line-breaks dont work in the headline. but its correct amount of letters in every box.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gentium}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, arrows.meta, ext.paths.ortho, ext.positioning-plus, graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % \tikzstyle bad
  box1/.style={rectangle, draw=black, align=center},
  pfeil1/.style={draw=black, -Stealth},
  heading/.style={node font=\Large\bfseries, draw=black},
  a bit to the left/.style={xshift=-.3333em},
  a bit to the right/.style={xshift=+.3333em},
  backbox/.style={draw=gray!25},
]
\node[box1] (v1) at (0,0) {ddddddddddddddd \\ \textit{ddddddd}};
\node[box1] (v2) [below=of v1] {dddddddddddd \\ \textit{dddddddd}};
\node[box1] (v3) [below=of v2] {ddddddddddd \\ \textit{dddddddd}};
\node[box1] (v4) [right=of v2] {dddddddd \\ \textit{ddddddd}};
\node[box1] (v5) [right=of v4] {ddddddd \\ \textit{ddddddd}};
\node[box1] (v6) [right=of v5] {dddddddddd \\ \textit{dddd}};
\node[box1] (v7) [below=of v6] {dddddddddd \\ \textit{ddddddddd}};
\node[box1] (v8) [below=of v7] {dddddddddd \\ \textit{ddddddddd}};
\node[box1] (v9) [below=of v8] {dddddddddddddddddddddd \\ ddddddddddddd \\ \textit{ddddddddddddd}};

% right=of (…)(…) is basically:
% fit a tight node around both v7 and v8 and
% place the new node to the right of that.
% this vertically centers the v10 node between v7.north and v8.south
\node[box1] (v10) [right=of (v7)(v8)] {\textit{dddddddd}};

\path (v1) -- node {+} (v2); % no \draw but \path
\path (v2) -- node {+} (v3); % no \draw but \path
\path (v2) -- node {=} (v4); % no \draw but \path

\graph[use existing nodes, edge=pfeil1] {
  % this is the same as \path[pfeil1] (v4) edge (v5) (v5) edge (v6) (v6) …;
  {[path, --] v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9},
  % this is the same as \path[pfeil1] (v7) edge[horizontal vertical horizontal] (v10)
  %                                   (v8) edge[horizontal vertical horizontal] (v10);
  % or, even more plain: \path[pfeil1] (v7) -|- (v10);
  %                      \path[pfeil1] (v8) -|- (v10);
  {v7, v8} ->[horizontal vertical horizontal] v10
};

% see above, once again:
% head1 is above of a rectangle around v1 and [a bit to the left]v5.north
% head2 is above of a rectangle around v10
%   and the point at the intersection of the vertical through v5
%                                    and the horizontal through v1
%       … and a bit to the right
% Now, the - instructs the node to be as wide as these rectangle
% (it's a horizontal fit, other options are | for a vertical fit and + for both)
\node[heading, above={of -(v1)([a bit to the left]v5.north)}]      (head1) {ddddddddddddddddddddddd // ddddddddddddddddddddd };
\node[heading, above={of -([a bit to the right]v5|-v1.north)(v10)}] (head2) {ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd // (this could be smaller letters and several lines but the amount of letters is correct, brackets includedxxxxxxx)};

% I'm sure we don't want to paint all over our diagram so we're using the background layer
% and once again "fit" rectangles around already present nodes
\scoped[on background layer]
  \node[backbox, fit=(head1)(v3.west|-v9.south)]{}
   node[backbox, fit=(head2)(v9), fill=gray!10]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Is this what you want?
I'm using my own TikZ libraries from my tikz-ext package to solve some things:

ext.paths.ortho provides the path operation -|- which is available as a to path as horizontal vertical horizontal.
ext.positioning-plus provides extensions to positioning-plus and combines this with the fit library.

I've commented this in the code below, I hope this makes it clear enough.
I'm also using the graphs/\graph syntax for an easy way of connecting the nodes but I've also commented the basic commands.
The backgrounds library is used to place nodes/rectangles below other nodes.
Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, arrows.meta, ext.paths.ortho, ext.positioning-plus, graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % \tikzstyle bad
  box1/.style={rectangle, draw=black, align=center},
  pfeil1/.style={draw=black, -Stealth},
  heading/.style={node font=\Large\bfseries, draw=black},
  a bit to the left/.style={xshift=-.3333em},
  a bit to the right/.style={xshift=+.3333em},
  backbox/.style={draw=gray!25},
]
\node[box1] (v1) at (0,0) {box 1 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v2) [below=of v1] {box 2 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v3) [below=of v2] {box 3 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v4) [right=of v2] {box 4 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v5) [right=of v4] {box 5 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v6) [right=of v5] {box 6 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v7) [below=of v6] {box 7 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v8) [below=of v7] {box 8 \\ \textit{dd}};
\node[box1] (v9) [below=of v8] {box 9 \\ dd \\ \textit{dd}};
% right=of (…)(…) is basically:
% fit a tight node around both v7 and v8 and
% place the new node to the right of that.
% this vertically centers the v10 node between v7.north and v8.south
\node[box1] (v10) [right=of (v7)(v8)] {\textit{box 10}};

\path (v1) -- node {+} (v2); % no \draw but \path
\path (v2) -- node {+} (v3); % no \draw but \path
\path (v2) -- node {=} (v4); % no \draw but \path

\graph[use existing nodes, edge=pfeil1] {
  % this is the same as \path[pfeil1] (v4) edge (v5) (v5) edge (v6) (v6) …;
  {[path, --] v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9},
  % this is the same as \path[pfeil1] (v7) edge[horizontal vertical horizontal] (v10)
  %                                   (v8) edge[horizontal vertical horizontal] (v10);
  % or, even more plain: \path[pfeil1] (v7) -|- (v10);
  %                      \path[pfeil1] (v8) -|- (v10);
  {v7, v8} ->[horizontal vertical horizontal] v10
};

% see above, once again:
% head1 is above of a rectangle around v1 and [a bit to the left]v5.north
% head2 is above of a rectangle around v10
%   and the point at the intersection of the vertical through v5
%                                    and the horizontal through v1
%       … and a bit to the right
% Now, the - instructs the node to be as wide as these rectangle
% (it's a horizontal fit, other options are | for a vertical fit and + for both)
\node[heading, above={of -(v1)([a bit to the left]v5.north)}]      (head1) {Left part};
\node[heading, above={of -([a bit to the right]v5|-v1.north)(v10)}] (head2) {Right part};

% I'm sure we don't want to paint all over our diagram so we're using the background layer
% and once again "fit" rectangles around already present nodes
\scoped[on background layer]
  \node[backbox, fit=(head1)(v3.west|-v9.south)]{}
   node[backbox, fit=(head2)(v9), fill=gray!10]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output


Thank you very much! That's exactly what I mean! :- )
I read your text sometimes, and I'm sure: I would not have been able to write that by myself ^^

After replacing the textual placeholders, I found the gray background + the special arrow do get a bit irregular. It's not really a big problem, but it's not looking perfect. :-) Can I reach out to you, sending you the original text? Can not find a way to contact you private.

You probably want {v7, v8} ->[horizontal vertical horizontal, /tikz/ortho/distance=-.5*x_node_dist] v10 so that the the -|- arrows meet at the same point. I can't really think of something that could go wrong with the background areas … unless the headings are actually wider as the areas. Feel free to replace your actual text with placeholders that have the same height and width …

Okay, I switched the text to placeholders. To be really exact, there is a little commentary in brackets in the second headline.... so it's actually looking completely messed up cause the line breaks don't work in the headline.... if that's not easy to fix, I would just don't write the small commentary there.

@Schnabel Well, you need align=center for those nodes, add that to the heading style. For the other nodes, this is part of the box1 style.

But the gray background also got spread out? Never mind, I can stay with that little imperfection.

@Schnabel Sorry, I just saw that you actually edited your question. First of, I'm assuming you meant \\ instead of //. But still, the heading boxes are wider than the nodes. You're either missing more line breaks or I'm missing something. Automatic line-breaking only happens with a set text width (or other LaTeX means). Do you want that?

The gray background is not really scaling with the rest, I think it's because there are fixed numbers defining in that place, not something like "relative to"... And that double arrow looks a bit uneven. But these are really small details. I wouldn't got even to the actual point:) my knowledge about this is \tiny :))
